# Computed Column Specification - Validation error on working query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to set the value of a column based on another column's value by using *Computed Column Specification* in SQL Server.

Basically I want to set the columns' value to be a link if it has a result associated (in another column). This is what I tried putting in the *formula* part of that column but I always get this

> *Error Validating formula*

T-SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN D.TestResultId IS NOT NULL 
       THEN ('<a href="Analysis?Result=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), D.TestResultId) + '">Analysis</a>')
       ELSE 'Pending Analysis' 
    END
FROM DailyReport AS D
```

The query by itself is working fine, but when put in that into the *computed column specification* it always returns that error. I even tried creating a stored procedure and calling it, but still the same issue. Can I get any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `SELECT - FROM` part on the computed column. It should just be:

```
CASE WHEN TestResultId IS NOT NULL 
THEN ('<a href="Analysis?Result=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), TestResultId) +
'">Analysis</a>') ELSE 'Pending Analysis' END
```

Comment: Tried also, still the same problem

Comment: @AleTiro - Sorry, did you removed the alias on your column?. As it is now on my answer?

Comment: Totally overseen that. And I was trying it so desperately even before i posted on SO. Thanks a lot, have a couple of reputation points :)